# Password Hash Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, hash, passwords

I don't know much about hashing passwords, but I'd like to know. I'd like to know how good the following algorithm is for a normal site without credit card information or something like that, and I also want to know how to improve it.
The algorithm is:

```
hash('sha512', crypt(hash('whirlpool', $password.$username), base64_encode(md5(strlen($password)))))
```

Comment: What's to prevent a playback attack?  It won't stop anyone from recording and playing back your (nonchanging, static) string.  By the way, mixing up various hashes (whirlpool, sha, md5) is a really bad idea.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix more than one hash, each one is optimized to work best by itself.

Depending on what you are using that hash for it's also a very bad idea to put $password in it. If it is being stored on the user's computer that is, like in a cookie. You don't want that in there.

If you store the hash in a database you can also make it better by adding a dynamic random string before using the hashing algorithm. Then a new hash will be generated for the user each visit.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend using a [well-known, tested, vetted hash/crypt function](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) over any home-grown algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class that I created to store a id/password combos for an api I integrate with.  Each user can have their own unique credentials.  I do not advise storing any credit card data on a non PCI compliant computer.

This is my exact class but you have some missing pieces so I have commented those.  Please note that the vector is unique (Think of it as a hash) and I store that in the database along with the encrypted data.

The key is out of the public directory which goes to another topic of securing your box.

```
<?php
// This is on my index page but added here so you see all constants.
define('DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');


class locker {
  private $algorithm = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
  private $key;
  private $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
  public $iv;  // Public so we can change to the one used to encrypt it.

  public function __construct()
  {
    // Lets include our key
    // The key is located Outside of the public directory.
    $this->key = file_get_contents(DIR .'../keys/passphrase.key');
    // Create the initialization vector for added security.
    $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->algorithm, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
  }

  public function encrypt($string)
  {
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt($this->algorithm, $this->key, base64_encode($string), $this->mode, $this->iv));
  }

  public function decrypt($string)
  {
    return base64_decode(mcrypt_decrypt($this->algorithm, $this->key, base64_decode($string), $this->mode, $this->iv));
  }

  // Helper functions so you can see what you can do on your own box.
  public function list_modes()
  {
    print_r(mcrypt_list_modes());
  }

  public function list_algorithms()
  {
    print_r(mcrpt_list_algorithms());
  }
}
?>

<?php
//Example usage
$locker = new locker;
$pass = $locker->encrypt('passwordvalue');
$iv = $locker->iv;

// Decrypt it
$locker = new locker;
$locker->iv = $iv;
$pass = $locker->decrypt($pass);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something strong. you have to 
- never save the password but a hash (don't need so much) to avoid db hack use of password.

- and never ask for the password but for a hash of the pasword hash + salt (the date for example) to avoid playback attack

Answer (score 0):

try this (very easy to use) class I wrote which includes automatic algorithm detection to get the most secure algorithm that your server supports: http://netentwicklung.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/87/